# Who has admin privileges for the bitcoin wiki?

Tags: bitcoin-wiki

Who has an admin user?
I know Stephen Gornick has. Who else?

Who besides MagicTux has technical admin credentials? (server access)

Comment: FYI, if you have admin right or know someone who does, there are a few issues that need their attention. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=94903.0 and https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=133974.msg1436221#msg1436221

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any mediawiki installation have a special page giving you the list of all the admins .

For the bitcoin wiki,find it at :

https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?title=Special:ListUsers&group=sysop

See also :

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Special:ListGroupRights

Comment: Currently shows magicaltux (controls the bitcoin.it domain and hosts the site), nanotube, genjix, kiba and myself,

Comment: @StephenGornick - Woot! I am now also an admin!